# Monitoring Real Time App Performance on Android and iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, monitoring

Are there any tools / services out there to log performance data (open times, events etc.) from inside iPhone or Android apps as they run on the devices? [e.g. like new relic but actually running on the phone for a specific app.]

Comment: Are you trying to monitor native-language apps or apps developed through third-party services?

Answer (score 2):

**iOS**

Instruments
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-time-profiling-with-instruments/

**Android**

Traceview to profile Java code
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

ARM DS-5 Community Edition for native code
http://ds.arm.com/ds-5-community-edition/

There should be plenty of questions on this topic already.

Edit: sorry, I missed the part about viewing performance data live

Comment: Yep - really not looking for development time tools - but tools when the app is running in production.

Comment: With Instruments you can profile the app while it's running on the physical device, so its made for you. Probably the same is for Android.

Comment: Yes, but this isn't what I mean. I mean getting performance data checkpoints of *all* of the live instances of my app which are out in the wild. Specifically assume the app is making API calls - that affects how it behaves. I'd like to get realtime info from all those apps as to how responsive the API is and how the user perceives it.

Comment: I'll give you the bounty since you added the most - but question isn't really answered!

Answer (score 1):

Check our Crittercism.  We have recently released a solution that tracks real time app performance (latencies, error rates, data in/out etc.) - from within the app.

Disclaimer - I work for Crittercism. But our solution still rocks :-)

Answer (score 0):

here is [something](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/316-a-timing-utility/) for iPhone. Don't program for Android so can't help you there but the process should be the same. Then you capsulate the methods into the timing function and see how long it takes on the device.